# Pager not working in IE > 9 on jqGrid and angularJS

Tags: angularjs, jqgrid

I have had a page running for a while now using AngularJS to call some data from a Spring controller and render a jqGrid.  I am using AngularJS 4.1.9 and jqGrid 4.13.4.  This page has always had a problem in IE which I have sidestepped by setting the IE version to 9 with a metatag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

I now want to remove this metatag and am investigating what the problems are.  One problem was that I had two formatters on my colModel columns which Chrome/IE9 didn't mind but IE > 9 did.  This was a mistake and easily fixed.

The other problem is with the pager.  I am setting my jqGrid pretty much according to the examples as far as I can see

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    colNames :[...],
    colModel: [...],
    guiStyle: "bootstrap",                                  
    searching : {defaultSearch:"cn"},
    loadonce: true,
    pager:true,
    sortname:"LastName",
    sortorder:"asc",
    forceClientSorting: true,
    rowNum:25,                                  
    rowList:[25,50,75,100],     
    pager: "#pager",
    footerrow:true,
    rownumbers:true,
    data: $scope.data,
...
```

If I run the code like this it fails and the only message I get  (in Developer Tools) is 'Controller is Undefined' in the app.js file where the controller is defined

```
App.controller('paController',paController);
```

If I remove the line

```
pager: "#pager",
```

everything works properly (except the paging arrows are not there !)

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: could you provide **the demo**, which reproduces the problem? Moreover I'd recommend you to use **always** the latest version of free jqGrid: the version 4.15.2 currently. Instead of usage `pager: "#pager"` you can use just `pager: true` and you don't need to have empty pager div `<div id="pager"></div>`. Specifying *two properties with the same name* is syntax error in many web browsers (see `pager:true,...,pager: "#pager"` in your code). The usage of `loadonce: true` in case of usage *local data* (see `data` parameter) is unneeded (wrong) too. It amde a problems in old version of free jqGrid

Comment: Many thanks that's fantastic.  Solved the problem I was fiddling with for a few hours!